# Does updating an objects property retrieved from memcache update the property in the datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine

First, I retrieve an object from memcache:

```
player = memcache.get('%s' % id)
```

Then I update one of its properties:

```
player.score = newScore
```

I've done a bit of testing and it seems as it these two lines change the property player.score in my datastore. Now, I don't know much about memcache, but I do not expect this behavior.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to save the changes after updating your player object, put it again to the datastore:

```
player.score = newScore
player.put()
```

Comment: Apologies, I indeed do
    player.put().
Does player.put() update my datastore even though the object was retrieved from memcache?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but only if you cached this object after performing first put() on it. After first put the object gets its Key, which is saved within the entity. Calling put() on entity, which already has a key is a  update operation.

Comment: I first add player to datastore and run player.put(). Next I retrieve it from memcache, update one property and run player.put() again. Hence, based on what you just said, the property in the datastore should be updated as well.
Thank you.

Comment: Doing this will overwrite the entire datastore entry - so any changes made since you stored it in memcache will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Python, I think you are seeing the effect of [NDB caching](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache), specifically, the [memcache-backed caching](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache#memcache). <strike>So yes, the behavior is expected.</strike> Apparently not, since both the OP and the BDFL had said that the code is not using NDB.

Comment: Am I automatically using NDB if I'm using Python? It says in the documentation that it is an alternative to the datastore, and I'm using the datastore...

Comment: It's not an alternative to the datastore, it's an altrernative inferface. You are using whatever you've imported in your file. If you've imported NDB, you are using NDB. If you make your model tempalte using (ndb.something) then you are using NDB.

Comment: We can't tell from the code given so far whether the OP is using NDB, but my guess is not -- if he were using NDB, he wouldn't be storing instances in memcache directly; he would be using NDB's memcache integration.

Comment: My apologies. I am not using NDB, nor did I know it was an option until Ibrahim mentioned it.